# Nikon D300 with Viltrox JY-110 Wireless Trigger

Tags: wireless-triggers, nikon-d300

Has anyone used a Nikon D300 along with a Viltrox JY-100 wireless tx and rx units?  The reason I ask is that when I insert the rx unit into the 10 pin connector and turn on the D300, I will get one opportunity to focus and shoot.  After the first attempt, I lose the ability to refocus and no further exposures are displayed on the viewscreen until I turn off the camera and remove the receiver from the 10-pin connector.  Is this a common situation?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Wireless Remote Shutter is defective. It should not operate that way.

I could not find any reference to a Viltrox JY-100 or JY-110. Do you have a JY-120 or JY-710?

[image]

[image]